# how to get the combinations of three columns of a table in pl/sql?

Tags: database, oracle, plsql, combinations, multiple-columns

I have to find out the combinations of three columns of a table in a DB using PL/SQL. For intance, consider the following abstracted table(A,B,C stand for Colum names and v1,v2, v3... stand for column values):

```
-+-----+-----+-----+-
-|  A  |  B  |  C  |-
-+-----+-----+-----+-
-|  v1 |  v2 |  v3 |-
-+-----+-----+-----+-
-|  v4 |  v5 |  v6 |-
-+-----+-----+-----+-
-|  :  |  :  |  :  |-
    :     :     :
```

My module should produce the each combination of these three columns A, B, C, like:

```
v1 v2 v3
v1 v2 v6
v1 v5 v3
v1 v5 v6
........
v4 v2 v3
v4 v2 v6
v4 v5 v3
v4 v5 v6
........
 :  :  :
 :  :  :
```

and so forth.

Can any one suggest the most efficient algorithms for this procedure? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A cartesian join will produce all the combinations you are looking for. As all three columns are in the same table, you need to split the table temporarily into three pieces:

```
SELECT *
  FROM (SELECT a FROM mytable),
       (SELECT b FROM mytable),
       (SELECT c FROM mytable);
```

Comment: Incorrect syntax near ','.

Comment: @G.Ciardini: can't reproduce your error, just checked, works for me